# Get better quality picture from camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I take a picture in Android via

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

and show / save it via

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView theImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
            theImage.setImageBitmap(photo);

            // try to save its
            try {
                File testFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.png");
                testFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(testFile);
                   photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This works fine, however the quality of the image is very bad. I do not know why, since I take the picture with 8 mega pixels.

Is there a way to do this without requiring the camera manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a closer look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) post: there are two ways to capture an image in Android. First one is designed for taking small and lightweight pictures - that's the approach you use, and the second one captures full-sized pictures and writes them to storage. The post describes both ways of accomplishing this task.